# Generalized partial trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I am interested in finding a general rule (from the matrix point of view) for calculating the partial trace. 
Starting from a matrix 
$$ A = X_1 \otimes X_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes X_n $$
I know how to take the partial trace for the case of only two $2\times 2$-matrices $X_i$ :
$$
    \def\Tr{\mathrm{Tr}}\Tr(A)_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
  A_{1,1} + A_{2,2} & A_{1,3} + A_{2,4}\\ 
  A_{3,1} + A_{4,2} & A_{3,3} + A_{4,4}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
    or element $(i,j)$ of the partial trace is the sum of elements $(i,j)$ of the diagonal blocks.

and with respect to the other subsystem
$$
    \bigl(\Tr(A)_1\bigr)_{i,j} := \Tr({\text{$(i,j)$-block of $A$}}) 
$$
Question: How can I generalize this in a simple way for $n$ matrices $X_i$ ?

Comment: I don't understand the "Tr(A)_1 = ..." equations. What is the meaning of the brackets?

Comment: Sorry, just thought of writing them explicitly as matrices (like in Python) ,but then I saw that it would be more useful to write them in words.  Brackets mean lines so a matrix can be written as [ [line 1] , [line 2], etc ]

Comment: Hmm. I still don't really understand the logic. Do you have a block matrix? If not, what are the "diagonal blocks" or "(i,j)-blocks"? Also, I suspect a typo, since one of your brackets is a sum of 2 addends while the other is a sum of more than 2 addends.

Comment: ok, let me simplify the question: Is there a general explicit way of writing the partial trace of a matrix constructed as the tensor product of n matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $ A = \sum_{l=1}^m X_1^l \otimes X_2^l \otimes \cdots \otimes X_n^l $ then $tr_i(A)=\sum_{l=1}^m tr(X_i^l)X_1^l \otimes X_2^l \otimes \cdots X_{i-1}^l \otimes X_{i+1}^l \otimes \cdots \otimes X_n^l $.

Now, $tr(X_i^l)=\sum_{s=1}^ne_s^tX_i^le_s$, where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, where $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the set of column vectors with $n$ complex entries and $X_i^l$ is a complex matrix of order $n$.

Thus, $tr(X_i^l)X_1^l \otimes X_2^l \otimes \cdots X_{i-1}^l \otimes X_{i+1}^l \otimes \cdots \otimes X_n^l=\sum_{s=1}^n L_s^t(X_1^l \otimes\cdots \otimes X_n^l)L_s$, where $L_s= Id_1 \otimes Id_2 \otimes \cdots Id_{i-1}\otimes e_s \otimes Id_{i+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes Id_n$ and $Id_t$ is the identity on the system $t$.

Finally, $tr_i(A)=\sum_{s=1}^nL_s^tAL_s$.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work quite well. :)

Comment: @qubix You are welcome.